# How to draw a linear graph in LaTeX using tikzpicture for the equation (22-x)/2?

Tags: overleaf, graphs, mathspec

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xmin = 0, ymin=0, xlabel={$\omega_{m}$},ylabel={T}]
        \addplot[red, ultra thick](x, (22-x)/2);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: any news? Does answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a complete small document which reproduce your problem.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    xlabel={$\omega_{m}$},
    ylabel={T},
    label style = {below left},
    xmin=0, xmax=28, xtick={22},
    ymin=0, ymax=13, ytick={11}]
\addplot[red, ultra thick, domain=0:22] {(22-x)/2};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```